# How to loop through 100 Url and extract info from each one with selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, automation

I have this list, what is the best to go to extract a piece of info from each one and store this info into another list 
**consider the wanted info <*a>hello world<*/a>**

```
def pagination():
    pagination = range(1, 100)
    for p in pagination:
        page = f"https://www.xx.xx{p}"
```

Comment: can you be more brief the question?Like what is main goal

Comment: extract a title inside every page

Comment: And what blocking you to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with a single host. so you have to maintain the `session` object firstly so you will avoid to be blocked or flagged by almost of sites firewalls as `DDOS-Attack`, where you actually maintain the same `TCP` socket stream without keep open/close/reopen the socket.

After that you can loop over your desired pagination parameter and extract the title.

Below is an example for that.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for page in range(1, 11):
            r = req.get(url.format(page))
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            print(soup.title.text)


main("https://www.example.com/page={}")
```

Comment: You should add the ```.text``` method ```print(soup.title.text)```