# How to get all products from a beautifulsoup page

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I want to get all the products on this page:

> nike.com.br/snkrs#estoque

My python code is this:

```
produtos = []
def aviso():                               
 print("Started!")                                
 request = requests.get("https://www.nike.com.br/snkrs#estoque")
 soup = bs4(request.text, "html.parser")
 links = soup.find_all("a", class_="btn", text="Comprar")
 links_filtred = list(set(links))
 for link in links_filtred:
  if(produto not in produtos):
   request = requests.get(f"{link['href']}")    
   soup = bs4(request.text, "html.parser")     
   produto = soup.find("div", class_="nome-preco-produto").get_text()
   if(code_formated == ""):                         
    code_formated = "\u200b"
   print(f"Nome: {produto} Link: {link['href']}\n")                                                     
   produtos.append(link["href"])
aviso()
```

Guys, this code gets the products from the page, but not all yesterday, I suspect that the content is dynamic, but how can I get them all with request and beautifulsoup?  I don't want to use Selenium or an automation library, how do I do that?  I don't want to have to change my code a lot because it's almost done, how do I do that?

Comment: You can call the [feed](https://www.nike.com.br/Snkrs/Feed?p=1&demanda=true) directly and loop over `p` parameter with increasing int (eg 1, 2 and 3) & so on.

Comment: Got it, I'll apply this and see the result, thanks :)

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη I just realized that this feed page doesn't have all that are in the url I mentioned in the question :(

Comment: it's already have it. from 1 to 5.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη  Hmm, I get it, it worked, but if it has 6 or 4 pages, how will I find out?

Comment: detect the demanda max count from the `JS` within the main url. otherwise loop and exit once no products shown ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη  I thought about it, but I asked to have other ideas and try to get a more elegant solution

Comment: Yes, We knew it :), Please for future questions. DO NOT fight your code or being lazy to check another solution as that may lead the contributors to be lazy too to provide an answer. You might be needing to check [ask] :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DO NOT USE requests.get if you are dealing with the same HOST.

Reason: [read-that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62443105/7658985)

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


def main(url):
    allin = []
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for page in range(1, 6):
            params = {
                'p': page,
                'demanda': 'true'
            }
            r = req.get(url, params=params)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
            goal = [(x.find_next('h2').get_text(strip=True, separator=" "), x['href'])
                    for x in soup.select('.aspect-radio-box')]
            allin.extend(goal)
    df = pd.DataFrame(allin, columns=['Title', 'Url'])
    print(df)


main('https://www.nike.com.br/Snkrs/Feed')
```

Output:

```
                                           Title                                                Url
0              Dunk High x Fragment design Black  https://www.nike.com.br/dunk-high-x-fragment-d... 
1          Dunk Low Infantil (16-26) City Market  https://www.nike.com.br/dunk-low-infantil-16-2... 
2                     ISPA Flow 2020 Desert Sand  https://www.nike.com.br/ispa-flow-2020-153-169... 
3                   ISPA Flow 2020 Pure Platinum  https://www.nike.com.br/ispa-flow-2020-153-169... 
4    Nike iSPA Men's Lightweight Packable Jacket  https://www.nike.com.br/nike-ispa-153-169-211-... 
..                                           ...                                                ... 
115                 Air Jordan 1 Mid Hyper Royal  https://www.nike.com.br/air-jordan-1-mid-153-1... 
116                       Dunk High Orange Blaze  https://www.nike.com.br/dunk-high-153-169-211-... 
117                         Air Jordan 5 Stealth  https://www.nike.com.br/air-jordan-5-153-169-2... 
118                   Air Jordan 3 Midnight Navy  https://www.nike.com.br/air-jordan-3-153-169-2... 
119                             Air Max 90 Bacon  https://www.nike.com.br/air-max-90-153-169-211... 

[120 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the data you can send a request to:

```
https://www.nike.com.br/Snkrs/Estoque?p=<PAGE>&demanda=true
```

where providing a page number between 1-5 to `p=` in the URL.

For example, to print the links, you can try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.nike.com.br/Snkrs/Estoque?p={page}&demanda=true"

for page in range(1, 6):
    response = requests.get(url.format(page=page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    print(soup.find_all("a", class_="btn", text="Comprar"))
```

Comment: What you are doing here within `soup.find_all` is actually a complete regex search under the neath! which will keep open each anchor `a` and check if class == `btn` and include a text `comprar` ! but in case if you use a selector. it's match according to parser logic not a regex.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη This is the same as OP's code for finding the links. I wasn't providing a full answer, just how to get the data between the pages using `range()`